# How to detect Windows shutdown in a WinForms app?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create an application in WinForms (C#) that'll be running continuously in my system and be able to detect windows shutdown/restart/logoff and create a shortcut key (eg esc) which will cancel the shutdown automatically whenever I want. But, first I need to learn how to detect when Windows shuts down using C# windows form application.

Comment: The FormClosing event fires with e.CloseReason set to CloseReason.WindowsShutdown.  There is no point in trying to cancel it, the OS will just ignore you.

Comment: ok thanks. I'll keep trying because I really need an app that can detect windows shutdown and give me option of cancelling it with a short key. I don't want to lose my work whenever I shutdown my system mistakenly, or to wait for the system to shutdown and have to start it again because I shut it down mistakenly.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
private static int WM_QUERYENDSESSION = 0x11;
private static bool systemShutdown = false;
protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg==WM_QUERYENDSESSION)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("queryendsession: this is a logoff, shutdown, or reboot");
        systemShutdown = true;
    }

    // If this is WM_QUERYENDSESSION, the closing event should be
    // raised in the base WndProc.
    base.WndProc(ref m);

} //WndProc 

private void Form1_Closing(
    System.Object sender, 
    System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (systemShutdown)
        // Reset the variable because the user might cancel the 
        // shutdown.
    {
        systemShutdown = false;
        if (DialogResult.Yes==MessageBox.Show("My application", 
            "Do you want to save your work before logging off?", 
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow... looks complicated. I'll try it and see. thanks